# Setting a custom font to a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts, jlabel

I'm doing a simple **Pong** game and wanted to add an 8-Bit font but can not figure how. 
This is the method I used for JLabels:

```
public void drawScore()
{
    player1 = "Player 1";
    player2 = "Player 2";


    JLabel leftScore = new JLabel(player1);
    JLabel rightScore = new JLabel(player2);

    leftScore.setForeground(Color.white);
    rightScore.setForeground(Color.white);

    leftScore.setLocation(20, 0);
    rightScore.setLocation(730, 0);

    leftScore.setSize(100, 40);
    rightScore.setSize(100, 40);

    add(leftScore);
    add(rightScore);
}
```

I tried solutions which I found on here and other web-sites and they didn't work out well either. There is a **.TTF** file in a folder called 'assets' -which I created- in **Java Project Folder** named **Pong**. It would be perfect if the right code not include `try` and `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Font fontAwesome;

static {
    try (InputStream in = YOURCLASS.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf")) {
        fontAwesome = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in);
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's an example with fontawesome. Paste that at the top of your class and then simply use 
`leftScore.setFont(fontAwesome);` to set the font.

Unfortunately you're going to need the try/catches. Note that the multicatch block might not work depending on your language level. If it doesn't just split them into two catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
try {
    InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("path/to/font");
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is); 
    Font sizedFont = font.deriveFont(18f);
    jLabel.setFont(sizedFont);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Not loaded");}
```

After you load the font you need to set a size to it!

You will have to use `try/catch` blocks to do this.